# Create multiindex columns based on column names and positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with column names like:

```
id name ... class maths_marks1 maths_marks2 eng_marks1 eng_marks2
```

Now I want to create Multiindex columns like: first column is `id` so it remains as is, then `maths` and `eng` in level0 while `marks1` and `marks2` in level1, and the rest of the columns under `student_data`. So my final dataframe should look like:

```
   student_data   maths         eng
id name ... class marks1 marks2 marks1 marks2
```

Do note that `...` indicate that there are a lot of columns between `name` and `class`, therefore I would like to specify them by position and not name (something like starting from the second column to the column just before the one which contains `maths`).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: checkout `wide_to_long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend `student_data_` in each col which is not contain '_' and split columns to convert them as `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = ['student_data_' + col if '_' not in col else col
                  for col in df.rename(columns={'id': '_id'}).columns]
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', 1).map(tuple)
```

```
# Before
>>> df
   id   name class  maths_marks1  maths_marks2  eng_marks1  eng_marks2
0   1  Louis    CP            20            19          18          17

# After
>>> df
     student_data        maths           eng       
  id         name class marks1 marks2 marks1 marks2
0  1        Louis    CP     20     19     18     17
```